# progress bar doesn't move ,after loading the website he does not disappear?

Tags: javascript, java, android, eclipse, apk

I have inserted this "Gmail Progress Bar" in my `WebView`, but it doesn't move, it's only displayed, and when the webpage is loaded I want it to disappear.

What am I doing wrong?

```
mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com/");
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient() {
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        ImageView progress = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgProgress);
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)progress.getDrawable();
        frameAnimation.setCallback(progress);
        frameAnimation.setVisible(true, true);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not Javascript - it's Java. Wrong forum/tag.

Comment: I fixed the English.